# how to get resource guid before provisioning any resource on azure portal via arm template, rest api

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

We want to get a resource guid before resource provisioning, if there is any api for the same will be helpful.

we tired looking at the deployment manager json but we didn't find also couldn't find an api

Comment: what do you mean? resourceId? its well known, essentially, if you know the resouce name, type and resource group

Comment: we know that resource guid is similar to deployment guid, but is there a way to get via any API at the time of provisioning

Comment: what is a resource guid?

Comment: @4c74356b41 not the resourceId we need resource guid/ deployment guid to fetch the price from rate card

Comment: then billing api would have that?

Comment: "Resource Guid" property on the "Resource costs" blade in the new Azure Portal is merely a deployment GUID for billing purposes on a specific resource

Comment: billing api has but there a lot of resource guid, it unique for each resource and each location, if it is available to what resource we are provisioning will be helpful while deploying a particular resource